# Find which event called the listener in Node.js

Tags: node.js

There is only one listener attached to several events like this:

```
// emitter is an instance of events.EventEmitter..    
emitter.on('event1', listener);    
emitter.on('event2', listener);    
emitter.on('event3', listener);    
emitter.on('event4', listener);    
function listener() { 
   // I need to find which event was emitted and as a result, this listener was called.    
}
```

Please note that `arguments.callee.caller.name` won't work in Node, since `events.EventEmitter.on` method calls an anonymous function and therefore the `callee.caller` has no name!

Thanks!

Comment: don't you pass an event object to the listener? Wouldn't the event object be enough?

Comment: It's possible to pass the event name as a parameter to the listener, but this is not a robust solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just make an intermediary "function" for each listener if I *really* need to know who called it:

For example:

```
emitter.on('event1', function(){
    //something special with this event
    listener();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could always pass the event as a string parameter to the `listener` function.

For example:

```
emitter.on('event1', function() {
    listener('event1');
});
```

Then your listener function could check for which event was called:

```
function listener(eventType) {
    if (eventType === 'event1')
        // Do something here
}
```

Comment: Not a solution. The idea is to share a 'single' listener among several events and not creating individual listeners for each event. You are creating a listener for the event and what you're doing here is a bad design.

Comment: Like Neal's answer above, you are sharing the 'listener' function among several events. If you need to know which event was called, you would have to implement the functionality specific to that event in an anonymous callback function before calling the 'listener' function (like Neal's answer) or pass the event name as a parameter to the 'listener' function inside an anonymous function (as in my answer).

Comment: By listener I didn't mean the function called "listener()" !!! I meant the function that is attached and fired when the event is emitted. If you create that function as an anonymous function (like your solution), then you're attaching it to the emitter and "implementing" it. Again, implementing the listener callback on each individual emitter is not an option and they must share a single callback. Also, sending event name as parameter is not a good design as I already mentioned above...

Comment: Ah I see, my apologies. You can understand my confusion when you have named the function in the example 'listener' as well. I'm not aware of how this particular problem would be solved though.

Comment: Well, I actually name the function "listener" on purpose :)